# How to combine columns of two files, remove duplicates, and fill in missing lines

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, awk

I have two separate files that I would like to combine. Each have 7 columns as such:

```
1 10 6 0.02 A 45 0.17
1 15 6 0.03 A 67 0.17
2 33 6 0.10 A 23 0.17
```

and

```
1 10 6 0.04 B 87 0.17
1 12 6 0.12 B 93 0.17
2 33 6 0.08 B 45 0.17
```

I would like to combine column 1 and 2 of each files while removing duplicates and then add column 4 5 6 from each file to the corresponding combination of column 1 and 2. Then if columns 1 and 2 don't match I would like them to be printed however for the file lacking for it to put 0 instead of column 4 5 and 6 such that the final file would be

```
1 10 0.02 A 45 0.04 B 87
1 12 0    0 0  0.12 B 93
1 15 0.03 A 67 0    0 0
2 33 0.10 A 23 0.08 B 45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward way to do this is to use a 2d array in awk

```
FNR==NR {a[$1FS$2][0]=$4FS$5FS$6; next}
        {a[$1FS$2][1]=$4FS$5FS$6}
END {
    empty="0"FS"0"FS"0"
    for(i in a)
        print i FS (a[i][0]? a[i][0] : empty) FS (a[i][1]? a[i][1] : empty)
}
```

You can save the script as a file and execute

```
awk -f main.awk file1 file2
```

**Explaination**

- The first line `FNR==NR` scans file1 and stores the desired columns `$4 $5 $6` with the associated key `$1 $2` in an array `a[$1FS$2][0]`
- The second line basically does the same thing on file2 but stores the value into the array `a[$1FS$2][1]`, notice that these array assigning operations will automatically remove duplicates since arrays in awk are **associative**, meaning that each key can appear only once
- On the final step inside `END`, print out each row and substitute each empty values into a predefined string `0 0 0`
- If you want the output to be sorted say by an ascending index value order, add a `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"` to the first line inside `END`

If you have time, it would be quite helpful to go through the well-documented [Gawk Programming Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/)

Comment: When I try to use the script suggested i get the error
awk: main.awk: line 2: syntax error at or near [
awk: main.awk: line 4: syntax error at or near [
awk: main.awk: line 6: syntax error at or near [

is there something wrong with use [

Comment: @DylanGirodat Hmm, what version of awk are you using `awk --version` ?

Comment: I am using the default awk that comes with Ubuntu 16.

Comment: @DylanGirodat I assume that means `GNU Awk 4.1.3`, however I couldn't reproduce the error you mentioned

Comment: I don't think there is a `[` on line 4, did you happen to alter the script?

Comment: I got it to work, I updated my awk and then there was no problem running the script. However, now when I run the program I end up with the output: 

1 10 6 0.02 A 45 0.17 

1 15 6 0.03 A 67 0.17

2 33 6 0.10 A 23 0.17

1 15 0.03 A 67 0 0 0

2 33 0.08 B 45 0 0 0

1 10 0.04 B 87 0 0 0

1 12 0.12 B 93 0 0 0 

so it appears to be reprinting the first file and then putting the columns 3 4 and 5 that are unique to the first file followed by 0 0 0 and then putting columns 3 4 5 from file 2 followed by 0 0 0 instead of the desired output as above.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo I got it to work, thanks for the help!

Comment: @DylanGirodat Glad you have resolved the problem!